# Jquery validation not working on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have been trying for days to get this validation plugin to work in jquery and am having no luck at all.

The code I am using is below.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Jquery Validation, Opening Jquery etc

    $(function(){

        $("#step1form").validate({
            rules: {
                firstName: {
                    required: true
                }
            }
        });
    });


</script>
<div class="info">We would love to help you out just give us a few details and you'll be on your way!</div>
    <form id="step1form" action="" method="POST">
    <input name="firstName" style="width: 100%; margin: 3px 0 3px 0; padding-right: 1%;" type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name (Required)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='First Name (Required)'">
    <input style="width: 100%; margin: 3px 0 3px 0; padding-right: 1%;" type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Surname (Required)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Surname (Required)'">
    <input style="width: 100%; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;" type="text" id="emailaddress" placeholder="Email (Required)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Email (Required)'">
    <input style="width: 100%; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;" type="text" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number (Required)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Mobile Number (Required)'"><br/><br/>
    <input style="float: right; width: 150px;" type="submit" name="submitstep0" value="Next Step"/>
    </form>
```

I have no idea why it is not working but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check for any console errors?

Comment: The page is not loading so I cannot.

Comment: It is stuck on the loading page at 0%

Comment: _stuck on loading page_?? can you brief on that? I mean are you able to type anything on the input you are validating?

Comment: So the website has a pre-loader that loads the page before displaying it, However the page is not getting passed 0% thus the form never shows as it never loads.]

Comment: then you should edit the question the post which is not working, sidenote: the validation is working https://jsfiddle.net/z0pk7pk4/8/

Comment: It is only when the jquery is added that the page will not load? I am confused?

Comment: You must have some errors in console... which is not letting your loader to finish..

Comment: Are you putting `<html>` and the other tags inside your page?

Comment: Does the page load if you remove the js?

Comment: Well, that is why the validation plugin is not working. Was it working before you tried to add the plugin reference and code?

Answer (score 1):

you have did everything right but just missed one thing,
you have to specify the name of every input type because validation plugin works on the element name.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Jquery Validation, Opening Jquery etc

            $(function(){

                $("#step1form").validate({
                    rules: {
                        firstName: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        lastName: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        email: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        mobile: {
                            required: true
                        }
                    }
                });
            });


        </script>
        <div class="info">We would love to help you out just give us a few details  and  you'll be on your way!</div>
            <form id="step1form" action="" method="POST">
                <input name="firstName" style="width: 100%; margin: 3px 0 3px 0; padding-right: 1%;" type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name (Required)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='First Name (Required)'">
                <input name="lastName" style="width: 100%; margin: 3px 0 3px 0; padding-right: 1%;" type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Surname (Required)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Surname (Required)'">
                <input name="email" style="width: 100%; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;" type="text" id="emailaddress" placeholder="Email (Required)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Email (Required)'">
                <input name="mobile"style="width: 100%; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;" type="text" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number (Required)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Mobile Number (Required)'"><br/><br/>
                <input style="float: right; width: 150px;" type="submit" name="submitstep0" value="Next Step"/>
            </form>
        </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation works on the 'type' attribute of the input.
So change the types of email and mobile number as shown below.

```
<form id="step1form" action="" method="POST">
    <input name="firstName" style="width: 100%; margin: 3px 0 3px 0; padding-right: 1%;" type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name (Required)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='First Name (Required)'">
    <input style="width: 100%; margin: 3px 0 3px 0; padding-right: 1%;" type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Surname (Required)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Surname (Required)'">
    <input style="width: 100%; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;" type="email" id="emailaddress" placeholder="Email (Required)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Email (Required)'">
    <input style="width: 100%; margin: 3px 0 3px 0;" type="number" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number (Required)" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Mobile Number (Required)'"><br/><br/>
    <input style="float: right; width: 150px;" type="submit" name="submitstep0" value="Next Step"/>
    </form>
```

Hope this helps!!